# How to group, sum and include in a single ActiveRecord query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a `User` model, which `has_one` `Picture` (`carrierwave` back-end) and `has_many` `journal`s.

I need to get the top N users with their maximum score (the sum of the `score` field in the `Journal` model).

I wrote this scope

```
scope :top, lambda { |n=10|
  joins(:picture, :journals)
    .select("users.*, pictures.image, sum(journals.score) as total_score")
    .order("total_score desc ")
    .group("users.id", "pictures.image")
    .limit(n)
}
```

It works, but, when I try to get the `Picture` with `User.top.picture` I get an extra request to the database.

If I `include(:picture)` in the `top` scope then the `total_score` field runs away.

How I can fix this query? I will be very pleased if you can advise about this topic.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where are you getting an additional call to the database?

Comment: I updated the question. I get addition query when run `User.top.picture`, because I can not cache picture model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this by outer joining `users` to a subquery for total score:

```
scope :top, lambda { |n=10|
  select("users.*, total_score").
    joins("left join (select user_id, sum(score) total_score from journals " +
      "group by user_id) total_scores on users.id = total_scores.user_id").
    order("total_score desc").
    limit(n).
    includes(:picture)
}
```

It uses some manual SQL so is more database-specific, but since it returns one row per user it's easy to understand and extend.

Comment: Thanks. It works, i've fix syntax a little, and thats it.